# Typeface returns null on Android 4.4 when looking at widgets inside a parent view when targeting API higher than 21

Tags: android, view, widget, android-appcompat

There seems to be a problem with the AppCompat widgets on android.support.v7. Basically, I am using `getLayoutInflator().inflate()` to load an XML layout into a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout viewgroup`. Then, I pass the viewgroup into a function that extracts the child views and attempts to look at the typeface of the child view if it is a TextView, Button or EditText. This works fine on Android 5 and above. However, on Android devices running 4.4.4 or below, the typeface of the child view returns null. Why would the widgets return null?

If I inflate the viewgroup, then add it to the parent activity and find the widget by id, then I can get the typeface.

I need to change the typeface of the child view if it is a TextView, button or EditText. And the code below works on Android devices running 5 and above but not below Android 5.

```
public void checkView(View view) {

// custom_typeface is already defined elsewhere in the code.
// If I check any of the widgets below for their typeface getTypeface(),
// it returns null on Android devices running 4.4.4 and below.

if (view instanceof TextView) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) view;
    Typeface custom_typeface = createTypefaceBasedOnExistingStyle(txt.getTypeface);
    txt.setTypeface(custom_typeface);
}

if (view instanceof EditText) {
    EditText edt = (EditText) view;
    Typeface custom_typeface = createTypefaceBasedOnExistingStyle(txt.getTypeface);
    edt.setTypeface(custom_typeface);
}

if (view instanceof Button) {
    Button btn = (Button) view;
    Typeface custom_typeface = createTypefaceBasedOnExistingStyle(txt.getTypeface);
    btn.setTypeface(custom_typeface);
}
}
```

If anyone has any input or solution to this problem, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @FireSun, not even close. The question is why the widget on devices running Android 4.4.4 and below return null when on devices running Android 5 and above return the typeface.

Comment: Create a folder named assets .. src->main->assets and put all your fonts in this folder

Can you check this ,seems to be working for me.. 
custom_typeface =Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), String.format("%s.ttf", name_of _ur_font));

Comment: @sunilsunny, the problem is not that I can't set a custom typeface. The problem is that I want to get the original typeface of a widget, check if it is normal, bold, italic, or bold italic and then set the custom typeface with the original style of the widget. Again, the problem I'm running into is that the widgets running on Android 4.4.4 return null when attempting to get the current typeface.

Comment: @David Ok .. Misunderstood the question.Glad that you were able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what is going on. It seems that when you inflate an XML layout and attempt to get the typeface of widgets that do not have the textStyle property defined in the XML file on devices running Android OS at 4.4.4 or below, the typeface has not been defined and therefore it'll return a null.

On Android devices running 5.0 and above, the widgets return a default typeface no matter what because the textStyle defaults to Normal.

The solution for devices running Android 4.4.4 and below is to define the textStyle to Normal in the XML file on widgets you'd like to change the typeface. That way, when the XML layout is inflated, the textStyle is defined and a typeface is created for that widget.

Alternatively, in the code, we can check if the typeface returns null and just create a new typeface with Normal text style.

I hope this make sense to anyone who comes across the same issue in the future.